# Magento Catalog List view on mobile devices

Tags: php, xml, magento, view, magento-1.9

I'm trying to set List view as default only on mobile devices. I want to keep Grid view as default on bigger screens. This is my list.phtml, I use a check to get the useragent.

```
<?php
    $forcelist = false;
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
        //False enables Category grid view to all devices
        $forcelist = true;
    }
?>
```

After this I did edit the check to get the right view. This looks like this.

```
<?php if ($this->getMode() != 'grid' || $forcelist): ?>
```

As you can see this forces to get the List view. Problem is users can't switch to Grid view on a mobile device anymore. Bigger screens do work fine on this way. I am struggling a bit with this now. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pure css solution.  So basically you want to use php to output both the grid and list view.  Then use CSS and media queries to display or hide based on the screen width.  I know this isn't truly testing whether or not a device is truly mobile but I'm sure if you tested it on mobile devices it should work fine.  The only problem I see in this method is that SEO might not be perfect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I also think this will give some problems with SEO. Also I am not really sure what this does with the performance of the catalog. The problem is that the site contains more than 15,000 products. Think I really need a server side solution.

Answer (score 0):

The class responsible for this is: `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`.

**Change the constructor to something like this:**

```
  protected function _construct() {
    Mage_Core_Block_Template::_construct();
    $this->_orderField = Mage::getStoreConfig(
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::XML_PATH_LIST_DEFAULT_SORT_BY
    );

    $this->_availableOrder = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();

    $isUsingMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
            Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
            $_SERVER
    );
    if ($isUsingMobile && Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode_mobile')) {
      $listSwitch = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode_mobile');
    } else {
      $listSwitch = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode');
    }
    switch ($listSwitch) {
      case 'grid':
        $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
        break;

      case 'list':
        $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'));
        break;

      case 'grid-list':
        $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'), 'list' => $this->__('List'));
        break;

      case 'list-grid':
        $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'), 'grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
        break;
    }
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml');
  }
```

(the above sample code uses config setting at 'catalog/frontend/list_mode_mobile', that is declared/set elsewhere, for the complete module see the github link)

I made a module for this, here:

https://github.com/mpalasis/Palasis_Mobilelistmode

for the curious: a minor, yet important detail is the line `Mage_Core_Block_Template::_construct();`. This skips the constructor in the parent class (which would generally undo our work here or just waste time) and calls the grandparent's constructor for other init tasks needed for this namespace.